# Problem with xy grid and menu in Microsoft Edge only

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've created a responsive dropdown/drilldown megamenu in Foundation 6.5.3.

It works great in every browser except Microsoft Edge and IE11. I expected problems in IE, but the edge issues threw me for a loop.

In Edge, the menu items get stacked vertically even though it is supposed to be a horizontal menu. As illustrated by this pen:

```
 https://codepen.io/denpub/pen/KLRQGO
```

right now the divs that wrap the menus and the one that wraps the large menu contain both the grid-x and cell styles:

```
 <div class="grid-x cell ..."></div>
```

seems to be the what causes the stacking issue and if I separate these like so:

```
 <div class="grid-x ..."><div class="cell"></div></div>
```

it fixes the stacking issue in Edge, but causes the menu to lose the nice flex spacing in all browsers as illustrated with this pen:

```
 https://codepen.io/denpub/pen/KLRojm
```

In IE11 all the menu items stack on top of each other. If anyone has a suggestion to resolve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is it's the `expanded` class on the parent menu. This could cause the `li's` to go full width when there is less space.

Comment: Wow so simple!! Thanks, Rafi! it resolved the issue in both Edge and IE